# How to consolidate duplicate rows (using multiple columns) and display other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, plyr

I have a data-frame like this:

```
ID   A   B   C   D
1    1   0   x1  y
1    0   0   x1  y
1    0   0   x1  y
2    0   0   x6  v
2    0   1   x6  v
2    0   0   x6  v
3    0   1   r5  t
3    1   0   r5  t
3    0   0   r5  t
```

column ID is unique and I want to remove all duplicated and aggregate column A and B by showing max or sum (there could be maximum only one '1' for each ID in column A or B) and display columns C and D that has same value for all unique IDs.

```
ID   A   B   C   D
1    1   0   x1  y
2    0   1   x6  v
3    1   1   r5  t
```

by using

```
aggregate(A~ID,data=df,FUN=sum)
```

I get only ID and column A but how could I aggregate A and B in the same time and also show columns C and D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.` to aggregate both columns `A` and `B` and specify `C` and `D` as group variables if you want them to show in the results:

```
aggregate(. ~ ID + C + D,data=df,FUN=sum)
#   ID  C D A B
# 1  3 r5 t 1 1
# 2  2 x6 v 0 1
# 3  1 x1 y 1 0
```

Another trick is to use `cbind` to explicitly specify which columns you want to aggregate:

```
aggregate(cbind(A, B) ~ ID + C + D,data=df,FUN=sum)
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: thanks. I have more than 70 columns like C and D to display, Is there any way to avoid typing 70 names?

Comment: All the 70 columns are unique for each ID? Could try something like: `aggregate(cbind(A, B) ~ .,data=df,FUN=sum)`

Comment: They all have same values for each unique ID like column C and D.

Comment: See the above comments. On the other hand, I would possibly prefer to extract those columns out as a separate data frame. aggregate on A, B and ID and then join back on ID, which might be more efficient.